# Go Build Error "build constraints exclude all Go files" when GOARCH=386 with import "C"

Tags: c, go, x86, cgo

I'm using CGO package to import C code, and I want to build an `x86` (*386*) windows version of it. I found out this should be done by setting `GOARCH=386`.
It builds properly on my default environment settings (GOARCH=amd64), however, when I set the environment variable to "386", I get error: **build constraints exclude all Go files in** my file.

```
// hello.go
package main

/*
int CFunc() {
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, Go!")
}
```

```
go.mod

module hello

go 1.16
```

I do:

```
go build
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\basse\source\repos\xhptdc8_babel\go\info\hello>go build
package hello: build constraints exclude all Go files in C:\Users\basse\source\repos\xhptdc8_babel\go\info\hello
```

Trials:

- Without import "C", I get no error.
- With **// +build windows,386** or **// +build windows,386,!cgo**, *before package main*, I still get the same error

All details are found in [Go Issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45579)

Setting

```
set CGO_ENABLED=1
```

Generates another type of errors:

```
F:/Work/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible F:/Work/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwthrd.a when searching for -lmingwthrd
F:/Work/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible F:/Work/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwthrd.a when searching for -lmingwthrd
F:/Work/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible F:/Work/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwthrd.a when searching for -lmingwthrd
F:/Work/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwthrd
.
.
.
```

Comment: Did you try setting `CGO_ENABLED=1` like in that issue?

Comment: Thanks Jim. Yes, I did, but got different types of errors:
```code
F:/Work/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwthrd.a when searching for -lmingwthrd
F:/Work/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwthrd
.
.
```

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant information, we cannot read long text or code in the comments.

Comment: These are not Go errors, you need the 32bit libraries as well to build the C code.

Comment: So, the solution is to use CGO_ENABLED=1 with fixing c compiler error.
What confuses me is why this code builds with CGO_ENABLED=0 on GOARCH=amd64.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this doesn't compile to anything without `CGO_ENABLED=1`, because the file requires cgo and a C compiler. You must have something else that is compiling, or you are mistaken about the command output.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I will check that

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Neville Cook, I added the answer to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to @JimB.

In the code, make sure you use `import "C"` & the correct `CGO` directives/libraries In go code, like:

```
/*
    #cgo CFLAGS: -Wall -g -I../../../../lib/include/
    #cgo 386   LDFLAGS: -L./ -l:../../../../lib/x86dummy/xhptdc8_driver
    #include "xhptdc8_interface.h"
*/
import "C"
```

And, when building the code, make sure you run the following commands:

```
set GOARCH=386
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m32
```

Detailed steps and lessons learned are mentioned [Build Go code that uses CGO and Custom Library](https://github.com/cronologic-de/xhptdc8_babel/wiki/cheat_sheet#build-go-code-that-uses-cgo-and-custom-library)